# How to delete (null) files outputted from .cxx code using system()

Tags: c, ubuntu, null, cmake

I have a .cxx file and cmake file to help compile. However, when I run the code on the linux terminal, the correct files are outputted, as well as some (null) files (i.e. (null).5252 ) . I am trying to use`system("sudo rm -- \(null\)*");` in the .cxx code to delete the (null) files, but it doesn't seem to be working. It gives me the error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string you are passing to `system()`, the parenthesis are being interpreted literally because of the backslash. This isn't really what you want. You want to pass the backslash along in the string, so you need to escape the backslashes themselves.

```
system("sudo rm -- \\(null\\)*");
```

Or you can quote the filename rather than escaping the parethesis.

```
system("sudo rm -- \"(null)*\"");
```